# Web service that has Edmx objects as parameters

Tags: web-services, wsdl, edmx

I feel like exposing an edmx class as a parameter to a web service is not a good idea. I feel like it's wrong design. eg.

```
[WebMethod]
MyWebservice(int customerID, UserProfile profile){
}
```

now UserProfile is a class generated by Edmx framework. You might argue if the profile object is an input then it will not get a proper id (edmx id) because it will be created out of the context (since the web service can be called from any external consumer).

But i'm also looking for more explanation why exposing edmx class as a web service is not a good design. If you think it's ok, please tell me.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally considered good design practice to keep the data contracts of a web service and the data model objects associated with a database separate, so that if required you could change the entity model used at the back of a web service, without having to change the interface that you expose to consumers of the service.

Comment: I agree! Thanks dave. you brought a good point; and there might also be some other points so if any one has a concept to add please comment on this or leave a reply.